# Webservice consumido via servlet erro 500 JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, jboss, servlet

Fala, galera!

Tenho um projeto, que resolvi dividir em dois: um core e um web. O core usa CDI com todas as regras de persistência e de negócio, expondo suas funcionalidades via webservices REST e JSon. Já o projeto web é só o html, com bootstrap e angular. "Porque você resolveu fazer assim, seu animal", alguém pode perguntar. Porque se, mais tarde, eu resolver fazer um app para celular, basta consumir os webservices já existentes. Achei que fica mais prático.

Antes de mais nada, ressalto que uso o JBoss AS 7, tanto em ambiente de desenvolvimento quanto de produção.

Pois bem, localmente, tudo está funcionando, quando mandei para o provedor de hospedagem, tudo funcionou beleza também. O angular chama os webservices, atualiza base de dados e tudo. Uma verdadeira belezura! Mas, como nem tudo são flores nessa vida, apareceu a circunstância de precisar fazer um upload de um arquivo texto. Foi quando começou minha tristeza.

Pesquisei como fazer com o angular e achei muito complicado. Resolvi fazer com uma servlet no meu projeto web mesmo. O usuário submete o arquivo, a servlet o recebe, trata e, para gravar o registro do cliente, aciona um webservice específico para isso, existente no projeto core.

Espero ter sido claro na minha intenção.

Localmente, em minha máquina funciona. Dá pau no ambiente de produção, lá no provedor. O que acontece é que, na hora de consumir o webserver do core dentro do servlet, recebo diacho de um erro 500 com esse stacktrace:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: <<www.nomedomeusite.com.br>>
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    br.com.bonysoft.servlet.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:205)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Todo o resto, as gravações, leituras e navegação funcionam (inclusive as que usam os webservice do core, via angular). Apenas a chamada ao webservice provenientes da servlet de upload me retornam esse erro. Vejam o código:

HTML:

```
<div class="container" >

    <form name="form1" id="form1" action="servletUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="container col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="padding-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">

            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">IMPORTAÇÃO DE PLANILHA DE CLIENTES</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <input type="file" size="150" name="file1" id="idfile1" style="width: 100%;">                           
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Confirmar upload</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="desistir();">Desistir da operação</button>
        </div>

    </form>


</div>
```

SERVLET DE TRATAMENTO DO ARQUIVO:

```
String uri = "http://www.meudominio.com.br/cliente/uploadCliente/fulano/fulano@gmail.com/fone1/fone2";

URL url = new URL(uri);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();

String ret = xml.toString();

connection.disconnect();
```

CÓDIGO RELEVANTE DO WEB SERVICE REST EXPOSTO

```
@GET
@Path("cliente/uploadCliente/{nome}/{email}/{fone1}/{fone2}")
public void uploadCliente(
        @PathParam("nome") String nome,
        @PathParam("email") String email,
        @PathParam("fone1") String fone1,
        @PathParam("fone2") String fone2) throws Exception {


    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.setEmail(email);
        cliente.setFoneResidencial(fone1);
        cliente.setFoneComercial(fone2);
        cliente.setNome(nome);

        clienteDAO.gravar(cliente);

        entityManager.flush();

 }
```

Uma vez que toda essa idéia funciona localmente e só acontece o problema ao rodar no JBoss da minha hospedagem, tenho quase certeza de que se trata de alguma configuração do JBoss. Algum parametro de segurança, sei lá.

Se alguém tiver alguma idéia, agradeço fortemente.

Abraço a todos

Comment: Sabe o IP do servidor em que estão implantados os WSs? Se sim, já tentou com o IP? Se for o mesmo servidor para os dois projetos, já usou `localhost` ou `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 1):

Como entendi, sua aplicação está fazendo uma chamada ao WS para um host desconhecido.

O endereço do WS que sera acessado pela sua Servlet tem de ser exatamente o endereço que você acessaria utilizando um browser por exemplo. A API vai realizar uma chamada remota, independente se está no mesmo host...